# How can I send an image with Selenium?

Tags: python, api, selenium, automation, bots

I'm building an Instagram chat bot, and I'm not sure how can I send a photo. The way Instagram DMs work, I've tried doing:

```
text_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea")
text_field.send_keys("/Users/kerq/PycharmProjects/APIs/Astro_images_2/2022-03-02_Record_Prominence_Imaged_by_Solar_Orbiter.jpg")
```

However, all it does is send the path, as a string. I've looked through Selenium's documentation, but it seems like there's no obvious way to do it.

The other option is to find the upload image button and navigate to the file, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<svg aria-label="Add Photo or Video" class="_8-yf5 " color="#262626" fill="#262626" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M6.549 5.013A1.557 1.557 0 108.106 6.57a1.557 1.557 0 00-1.557-1.557z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path><path d="M2 18.605l3.901-3.9a.908.908 0 011.284 0l2.807 2.806a.908.908 0 001.283 0l5.534-5.534a.908.908 0 011.283 0l3.905 3.905" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path><path d="M18.44 2.004A3.56 3.56 0 0122 5.564h0v12.873a3.56 3.56 0 01-3.56 3.56H5.568a3.56 3.56 0 01-3.56-3.56V5.563a3.56 3.56 0 013.56-3.56z" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"></path></svg>
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You are sending the file to a `textarea`, you hav to invoke click on _Upload_ or _Submit_ button for sure. Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: Done, finding the svg icon and clicking is no problem, but how would I go about selecting the file I want to upload?